# Transfer several joined tables from one database to another using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have several tables in my database A which are interconnected via foreign keys and contain values. These values need to be transfered to another database B, all dependencies must be preserved, but the actual (numeric) values of primary and foreign keys are, of course, of no importance.

What would be the easiest way to fulfill this task using SSIS?

Here are the approaches I tried but with no much success:

1. I implemented a really very sophisticated view with flattened data and a lot of redundancy in the data and bumped into the problem how to split the data from this flattened view into several tables connected via foreign keys. This might be a solution, but I would personally prefer to avoid the data flatenning step if possible.
2. I tried to copy the tables one-to-one using NOCHECK options to lift up the constraint checks and to perform insertion into PK and FK fields. This, however, confines my transfer to a complete new import, I cannot just "add" some new data to existing set of data that would be nice.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You said "I cannot just "add" some new data to existing set of data that would be nice." If you added an "AND NOT EXISTS " clause, using the primary key, this should be possible. Are you using an autoincrement (i.e. IDENTITY) column as the primary key? If so, is there another combination of columns which will be unique for each row? Is there a timestamp column in the table which indicates when the row was inserted?

Comment: @MichaelHarmon, yes, you are technically right, but the insert might fail partially that is absolutely unacceptable. Yes, I have a classic table with PK defined on an integer column with autoincrement and identity (uniqueness). For some tables I can find another unique identifier by pooling several columns together, but not for all tables (some of them are  just one-to-many tables joined via PK). I have timestamp field on some tables, not again not everywhere (only where we use it currently for concurrency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration Services has a Control Flow called **Transfer Database Task** and **Transfer SQL Server Objects** Task exclusive for what you need.

Here is a tutorial for what you need [**LINK**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2064/transfer-database-task-and-transfer-sql-server-objects-task-in-ssis/).